# How to determine if npm package is compatible with react-native?

Tags: npm, react-native

Is there a way to determine if a npm package is compatible with react-native ?

I read that to be usable in react-native they must have polyfill.   Is this something I can look for?

For example:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

I am learning react-native and javascript.  I was hoping to take advantage of the *many* existing npm packages.  However unless the package has "react-native" as part of the package name it does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE (8/7/2017): Have a look at Andre Staltz's ([staltz/react-native-node](https://github.com/staltz/react-native-node)) package which makes ALL node packages work with react native!

---

As I understand it, any package that is (( NOT )) DOM dependent, should work. With regard to the [rt2zz/redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) package, I only quickly looked it over but it appears as though they support the react-native store since they provide instructions for it.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'
persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage})
```

Comment: It sounds like there is no single thing to look for to determine if a package is react-native compatible.  While I expect most packages do not support react-native, If I find any 'react-native' imports it is likely compatible with react-native.  A package that is DOM dependent cannot work with react-native.  What do you look for to identify a package as being DOM dependent?

Comment: There's no easy way. You just need to look through the source code. You'll be fairly safe using utility frameworks such as lodash, underscore, moments. For the rest, I'd scan for obvious, tale-tale signs such as a dependency on [react-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) or  perhaps scan through references to React.createElement, React.createClass, React.DOM, and other potentially [DOM Related Top Level APIs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html)

Comment: Besides looking for DOM dependencies, in the case where the package was written for NodeJS, you should also look for uses of native Node API objects in the dependency tree, like `fs`, `path`, `net`, etc.